# Fantasy book about a hunter girl with powers, who encounters other hunters (and their animals), a portal, and a vampire

Tags: story-identification, books

A girl travels by train from her home town in the mountains, to a big town that wants the type of hunter she is. On the way, a mage is on the tracks and stops the train. She uses her power to make him leave.

After she gets to the city, she finds out the hunters have their own fans. All the hunters have animals (dogs I think) that come out of a portal to help them fight, and after a kill they eat the Mana for energy. At the end of the day, they go back to the city and send their animals back through the portal.

After she gets to be friends with another hunter, they switch places one day and her friend is murdered by a vampire. Her friend's animals join her pack.

Please help if you can, thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 5):

The "Hunter" trilogy by Mercedes Lackey. Her name is Joyeaux, and her Uncle is an important member of the city's ruling council. There are all sorts of magic monsters, which came through a rift after some sort of nuclear explosion during a war. The mage on the tracks was an elf. https://www.mercedeslackey.com/books/hunter/

Comment: Yes, I have the book and this is it.